# How to join table columns with JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I would like to send a product list as a response to the client and I want to join all the users from the products to the products list.

I have tried many things but I can't get working...

Tables look like:

Table Products:

```
Product_id Product_Name
0          Shoe
1          Bike
```

Table Users:

```
Product_id User_Id User_Name
1          3       Jake
1          5       Tom
0          9       Bob
```

I would like to list all products with the users that are using the product:

Exp response:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <productName>Shoe</productName>
        <productId>0</productId> 
        <users>
            <user>
                <userId>9</userId>
                <userName>Bob</userName>
            </user> 
        </user>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productName>Bike</productName>
        <productId>1</productId> 
        <users>
            <user>
                <userId>3</userId>
                <userName>Jake</userName>
            </user>
            <user>
                <userId>5</userId>
                <userName>Tom</userName>
            </user>
        </user>
    </product> 
</products>
```

Product:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Products") 
@NamedQueries ({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product .selectAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p")     
})

public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Product_id ")
    private Integer productId;

    @Column(name = "Product_name")
    private String productName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "usedProductId", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
      private List<User> users;

//...   
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "Users") 
    @NamedQueries ({
        @NamedQuery(name = "User.selectAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u")
})

public class User {

    @Column(name = "User_id")
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "User_name")
    private String userName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="Product_id")
    private Product usedProductId;

//...   
}
```

From that code I get the list of products but not users in it...Response looks like:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <productName>Shoe</productName>
        <productId>0</productId> 
    </product>
    <product>
        <productName>Bike</productName>
        <productId>1</productId> 
    </product> 
</products>
```

I don't know what I am missing here... Any tips?
Thanks you in advance!

Comment: *From that code*: which code? All we have is two entities, and a XML. But we have no clue how this XML is generated in the first place.

Comment: Your User mapping is a bit odd. The `@Id` is set on productId and that variable is duplicated which should end up in compilation error.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I updated it

Comment: join? join where? in a query? do we have to guess what you mean?

Comment: @DN1 it is updated

Comment: updated with what? You mean some NamedQuery? There is a lot of JPA documentation on the internet which tells you how to form JPQL to do a JOIN. Internet search would reveal those. Here's one http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#jpql_from

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that I do not quite understand in your mappings but try the following things

In `User`

remove

```
@Id
@Column(name = "Product_id")
private Integer productId;
```

if it not there for some special purpose, I am not sure why you have it there

change

```
// @Column(name = "User_id")
@Id(name = "User_id")
private Integer userId;
```

then try again

And to have code more clear you might want to change also

in `Product`

```
// @OneToMany(mappedBy = "usedProductId", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<User> users;
```

in `User`

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="Product_id")
private Product product;
```